# Consider a random variable X whose probability distribution function is given by $f(x)=$

Tags: statistics, expectation, variance

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
2k,  & \text{if $x$ = -3} \\[2ex]
0.4, & \text{if $x$ = 0} \\[2ex]
0.3  & \text{if $x$ =3 } \\[2ex]
k    & \text{if $x$ = -4} \\[2ex]
0    & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}$$

$(1)$ Find the value of $k$;

$(2)$ Find the cumulative function $F(x)$.

$(3$) Find the variance of X.

---

$1.$ The first part one must use the formula

$F(x)= P(X \le x) = \sum_{t \le x } f(t)$

$\Rightarrow \sum_{x=1} f(x) =1$

$2k+0.4+0.3+k =1$

$k=.10$

$2.$ For this part finding the cumulative function is giving me some difficulties.

$$F(x) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $x$ < -4} \\[2ex]
0.1, & \text{if -4 $ \le x <-3$ } \\[2ex]
0.4  & \text{if  -3$<x \le$ 0 } \\[2ex]
0.3    & \text{if $ 0<x \le 3$ } \\[2ex]
1     & \text{x $\ge 3$}
\end{cases}$$

This is from my interpretation it may not be **correct**.

$3.$ To Find the variance one uses

$\sigma^2_{x} = E(x^2) - E(x)^2 $

$E(X) = 2(.1)+.4+.3+.1 =1$

$E(X^2) = (2(.1)+.4+.3+.1)^2 =1$

$\sigma^2= (1)-(1)^2 =0$

Is this the correct way of finding $\mu_{1} \text{ and } \mu_{2}$?

Comment: Hint Re 2): $F(X)$ must be a non-decreasing function

Comment: hint Re 3):  Your interpretation for the expectation of the squared random variable is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CDF is incorrect, though you have written the correct formula.

Sum probabilities less than or equal to a given $x_i$ to yield $F(x_i)$.

$$ F(X) = \begin{cases} 0.1 \quad x = -4 \\ 0.3 \quad  x = -3\\ 0.7 \quad x = 0 \\ 1 \quad x =  3 \end{cases}$$

Your mean is also false.

$$\mu = \sum p_ix_i =- 0.1$$

Note that your variance is also false.  A random variable should have 0 variance of it is constant.

Comment: Why would $.3 ,  x=-3$? The question above says $.3, x=3$. I am still working on how you found the mean.

Comment: EDIT: Your mass function is different than the CDF.